# "Ich verstehe, warum du so verwirrt bist, denn ich habe so etwas auch erlebt" Does this sentence fit in the context?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage, phrase

A friend wrote me a letter, asking me how he should learn French, he was so confused and overwhelmed as he asked a lot of questions. 
Does this expression make sense, or in other words, does it fit in this context?

- Ich verstehe warum du so verwirrt bist, denn ich habe auch so etwas erlebt.

I wanted to use this expression as an introduction in the letter.
Do you have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: @Janka Do you think überfordert also fits in this context?

Comment: Yes, sure. You should think about the difference between *überfordert* and *so überfordert* though.

Answer (score 5):

Your sentence is completely right. But I would say something like:

> "Ich kann gut nachvollziehen, warum du so verwirrt bist. Ich habe so etwas auch schon erlebt."

Comment: Could you explain, _why_ you would split the sentence and use _nachvollziehen können_ instead of _verstehen_?

Comment: @Arsak  It is simply a choice of style. It sounds a bit more "typical German", i.e. when speaking about how educated native speakers would express themselves in a written letter. In oral communication it is different. In oral communication it could be as short as: ***Ja klar. Das kenn' ich.***